# $\cot\frac{A}{2} + \cot \frac{B}{2} + \cot \frac{C}{2} = \cot \frac{A}{2} \cot \frac{B}{2} \cot \frac {C}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Proving (if $x + y +z = 90$) -

$$\cos x (\cos (y - z) - \cos (y +z)) + \cos y (\cos (x - z) - \cos (x + z)) + \cos z (\cos (x -y)- cos (x + y)) = 2 \cos x \cos y \cos z$$

I've no idea about the solution of the Equation. I can't take common and the difference inside the cosine ratios are difficult to be removed.

Question - 
Prove that -

$$\cot\frac{A}{2} + \cot \frac{B}{2} + \cot \frac{C}{2} = \cot \frac{A}{2} \cot \frac{B}{2} \cot \frac {C}{2}$$ 
When $A + B + C = 180^o$

I tried to solve it like this here -

Let $\frac{A}{2} = x$, $\frac{B}{2} = y$, and $\frac{C}{2} = z$

Let $\alpha$ = $\cot x + \cot y + \cot z$
$$\Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{\sin y \sin z \cos x + \sin x \cos y \sin z + \sin x \sin y  \cos z}{ \sin x \sin y \sin z}$$
$$\Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{\cos x (\cos (y - z) - \cos (y +z)) + \cos y (\cos (x - z) - \cos (x + z)) + \cos z (\cos (x -y)- cos (x + y))}{2 \sin x \sin y \sin z}$$

Now, If I'd be able to prove the numerator as $2 \cos x \cos y \cos z$, then I'd be able to make the whole equation = $\cot \frac{A}{2} \cot \frac{B}{2} \cot \frac {C}{2}$

Comment: Do you want to prove that $\cot{a/2}$+$\cot{b/2}$+$\cot{c/2}$ = $\cot{a/2}$$\cot{b/2}$$\cot{c/2}$

Comment: @Haran Why are you repeating the question?

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$x+y = \frac{π}{2} - z$$

Then,
$$\tan{(x+y)} = \tan{({{{\frac{π}{2}}-z}})}$$

$$\frac{\cot{x}+\cot{y}}{\cot{x}\cot{y}-1} = \cot{z}$$

Hence, when $x+y+z=\frac{π}{2}$, we have:

$$\cot{x}+\cot{y}+\cot{z}=\cot{x}\cot{y}\cot{z}$$

Now, replace $x=\frac{A}{2}, y=\frac{B}{2}, z=\frac{C}{2}$,
$$\cot{\frac{A}{2}}+\cot{\frac{B}{2}}+\cot{\frac{C}{2}}=\cot{\frac{A}{2}}\cot{\frac{B}{2}}\cot{\frac{C}{2}}$$

Hence, proved.

Comment: (+1) Brilliant!

Comment: @haran can you try to do this in my way?

Comment: tan (x + y) changes to cot in next step?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the formulas
$$\cot\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{s(s-a)}{(s-b)(s-c)}}$$ etc
Then Show that
$$\sqrt{\frac{s(s-a)}{(s-b)(s-c)}}+\sqrt{\frac{s(s-b)}{(s-a)(s-c)}}+\sqrt{\frac{s(s-c)}{(s-a)(s-b)}}=\sqrt{\frac{s(s-a)s(s-b)s(s-c)}{(s-b)(s-c)(s-a)(s-c)(s-a)(s-b)}}$$
Write the left-hand side as:
$$\sqrt{\frac{s^2(s-a)^2}{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}+\sqrt{\frac{s^2(s-b)^2}{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}+\sqrt{\frac{s^2(s-c)^2}{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}$$
and this is 
$$\frac{1}{A}(s(s-a)+s(s-b)+s(s-c))$$

Comment: I've not seen any formula like that which you are using, isn't there a good alternative?

Comment: I've not read $$\cot \frac{\alpha}{2} = \sqrt({\frac{s(s -a)}{(s-b)(s-c)}})$$ also, there is a $\alpha$ in LHS but not in RHS, so, equation seems incorrect

Comment: This is absolutely correct, it called the half angle formulas!

Comment: I can't use it in the exams because I've not read that

Comment: How it's correct? If you can say that it's correct, then I can also say that $$\sin 1^o = \sqrt{a + b}$$

Comment: Okay, oh okay, I understood it, but you should tell that what are s , a , b and c....

Comment: that square roots made it's more complicated and there are tons of brackets to open...... But how you can say that I'll get a the solution at last?

Comment: Yes sorry, $a,b,c$ are side lengthes of a triangle and $s=(a+b+c)/2$

Comment: sides? I've not heard something like that I thought half angle of cot'd be the modification of $cot 2 \theta$ formula

Comment: No it is total easy you must use $$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ i have the proof on two Sheets of paper

Comment: I can also proof that it's area of triangle by just making three perpendiculars, but how do you know that complex equation will get me to the answer?

Comment: Since i have made the proof

Comment: Can you try in my way, I think Cancelling 2 and getting cos x cos y cos z might be easier?

Comment: Also, you are doing things like this in 3rd step $$\sqrt (a) + \sqrt (b) + \sqrt (c) = \sqrt(abc)$$ which I think isn't possible

Comment: It is possible since the denominators are all equal!

Comment: read my post carefully!

Comment: That Works! But can you try that proof in my way as I'm doing? I want to make numerator = 2cosx cos y cosz without disturbing denominator

Answer (score 0):

In a triangle $A+B+C=\pi$
$$\pi-C=A+B$$
Divide by $2$ on both sides
$$\frac\pi2-\frac C2=\frac A2+\frac B2$$
$$\tan\left(\frac\pi2-\frac C2\right)=\tan\left(\frac A2+\frac B2\right)$$
$$\cot\left(\frac C2\right)=\frac{\left(\tan \frac A2+\tan\frac B2\right)}{\left(1-\tan\frac A2\tan\frac B2\right)}$$
$$\cot\left(\frac C2\right)=\frac{\cot\frac B2+\cot\frac A2}{\cot\frac A2\cot\frac B2-1}$$
$$\cot\frac A2\cot\frac B2\cot\frac C2-\cot\frac C2=\cot\frac A2+\cot\frac B2+\cot\frac C2$$